# catching Unhandled IOErrorEvent in my entire application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, loader

I have a very big flex 4 project with many flex modules and flash assets.

i have many loaders `Loader()` in each component that loads several assets. is there a way to create a general IOErrorEvent Handler for my entire application that will catch whenever a loader tries to load something and fails or do i need to go to each loader and catch the event individually ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't, since IOErrorEvents don't bubble by default. You could override the Loader class with an auto-catching-IOErrorEvent-loader and replace every Loader in your application.